# Unable to read data from disk

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, hardware-failure

I'm unable to retrieve data from a disk in Windows 7.  It shows 4 GB of space used on the disk but I cannot see the files, it looks empty.

Answer (score 2):

Where did this disk come from?  Have you ever been able to access it before?  Have there been any recent events, or indications of hardware failure (weird sounds, disk thrashing?)

or **Could it contain hidden files?**  In an explorer window, try clicking "Organize", then "Folder and Search Options" then click the "View" tab.

Under "Hidden Files and Folders", click "Show hidden files, folders and drives"

Answer (score 1):

You might try Control Panel, Admin Tools, Computer Management, Storage/Disk Management, right click on subject disk, select Properties, Security tab, and view your User Account for allowable permissions over the drive, such as "read & execute", "read", and "List Folder Contents".  Compare and contrast your permissions to that of Administrator and other listed accounts. You may have to grant yourself new allowable permissions via the edit button, if you can.

Is it a Win 7 drive... or from a previous OS or other system?